# When onResume is called app throws ArrayIndexOutOfBouds

Tags: android, arrays, onresume

When I click home button onPause method is called but when I call application in front onResume is called and than it crashes.

There is code when index is out of bouds:

```
while (isRunning) {
                if (!ourHolder.getSurface().isValid())
                    continue;

                Canvas canvas = ourHolder.lockCanvas();
                canvas.drawRGB(02, 02, 150);
                fingerx = (x - (Gball.getWidth() / 2));
                fingery = (y - (Gball.getHeight() * 2));
                for (int i = 0; i < balls.size(); i++) { // here...
                    ballX[i] = i * 155;
                    canvas.drawText("" + score, 40, 100, paint);
                    canvas.drawBitmap(balls.get(i), ballX[i], ChangingY[i],
                            null);
```

Error is:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-9140
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=4; index=4
at com.example.mygame.GFXSurface$GameSurface.run(GFXSurface.java:199)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
```

I know index should be 5 here but if it is than application doesn't even start

OnResume:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    ourSurfaceView.resume();
}



public void resume() {
            isRunning = true;
            ourThread = new Thread(this);
            ourThread.start();
        }
```

Run method:

```
@Override
        public void run() {

            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                balls.add(j, RandomBall());
            }
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setColor(Color.RED);
            paint.setTextSize(100);
            paint1.setStyle(Style.FILL);
            paint1.setColor(Color.RED);

            while (isRunning) {
                if (!ourHolder.getSurface().isValid())
                    continue;

                Canvas canvas = ourHolder.lockCanvas();
                canvas.drawRGB(02, 02, 150);
                fingerx = (x - (Gball.getWidth() / 2));
                fingery = (y - (Gball.getHeight() * 2));
                for (int i = 0; i < balls.size(); i++) {
                    ballX[i] = i * 155;
                    canvas.drawText("" + score, 40, 100, paint);
                    canvas.drawBitmap(balls.get(i), ballX[i], ChangingY[i],
                            null);
                    if (x != 0 && y != 0 && mode == 0) {
                        if (fingerx < 0) {
                            canvas.drawBitmap(Gball, 0, fingery, null);
                        } else if (fingery < 0) {
                            canvas.drawBitmap(Gball, fingerx, 0, null);
                        }
                        else
                            canvas.drawBitmap(Gball, fingerx, fingery, null);
                        checkForCollision(i);
                    }
                    if (ChangingY[i] <= canvas.getHeight()) {
                        ChangingY[i] += 1 * speed;
                    } else if (ChangingY[i] > canvas.getHeight()) {
                        ChangingY[i] = -72;
                        if (speed <= 11)
                            speed += 0.25;
                        removeAndAdd(this, i);

                    }
                }

                ourHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please put whole onresume code...

Comment: Are balls, ballX and ChangingY all the same size?

Comment: Can you post the full run method of your Thread.

Comment: What is ChangingY?  Where is it defined?  Is ballX used somewhere else outside of your thread?

Comment: ChangingY is y path of the ball ballX is the x path of the ball ballX isn't used outside

Comment: If ballX is not used anywhere else, then why bother defining it as an array?  Why not just replace it with i*155 in your call to drawBitmap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looping based on the size of `balls` but within your loop you are accessing both `ballX`  and `ChangingY` using the index `i`.  If `ballX` is smaller than balls then you will get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Since you are updating the values within the array `ballX` during the loop, then you probably want to create a new array using the size of `balls` before the loop starts:

```
ballX = new int[balls.size()];
```

Don't know what ChangingY is, but you will need to make sure that is also at least as big as balls.

Comment: ballx are x position of four balls which are for example 1, 2, 3, 4

ChangingY is y position of four balls

I define this in onResume ?

Comment: You will need to show more code that shows where ballX and ChangingY are defined and initialised.